# Nearest Neighbors...

Tags: statistics

I'm really distraught about the following problem:

I got a plane in $2D$, where we have $N$ points on it, which are randomly (and independently) distributed.

For a very small area $A$, we can easily find the that the probability to find $n$ particles inside follows a Poisson distribution.

Now my question is:

We have two points, $A$ and $B$. $A$ is the nearest neighbor of $B$. What is the probability that $B$ is also the nearest neighbor of $A$?
I tried several things, but nothing works... Got someone an idea?

Best
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Draw A and B, A is the nearest point to B, draw a circle around B through A, say it has radius $r$. Draw another circle of radius $ r $ around A. This circle has no other points within its boundary if and only if B is the closest neighbour to A.

There are no points in the 'lens' where the two circles overlap, since otherwise A would not be the closest point to B. Then, since in this case Poisson events happen per area, we need to find the area of the 'remaining circle' around A (the area of the circle around A $ - $ the overlapping area of the two circles).

This area is: $ \pi(\frac{2\pi}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})r^{2} $

Calculated using information on this page: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Su12/Carreras/EMAT6690/Essay2/essay2.html

The probability that B is closest to A is then the probability that there are no points within the area above. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, the probability that there are no points in the area A is exp(-c*A), where c is the concentration. But I have to show that the probability is about 0.62, so I have to get rid of c somehow...

Comment: I would think that the concentration would be necessary, is there a way to calculate it with the information given to you in the question?

Comment: No, no further information :-( But I think it should not depend on the concentration in the end. The probably for that case should be the same, it's the same problem when we take a high concentration, but on a smaller scale, which does not infect the probablity.

Comment: @user235506: I suspect that you need to account for the distribution of $r$: when the concentration is high, $r$ and hence $A$ will tend to be smaller.